# How to remove files after LOAD DATA INFILE?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I'm using the `LOAD DATA INFILE` solution to speed up big inserts, like outlined here: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/12/insert-into-select-performance-with-innodb-tables/.

It works brilliantly, and very fast. However, when I do the select, I create a file, which is then used by the `LOAD DATA INFILE` command. But after using this file, I don't need it any more. Can I get rid of it with an additional query? Or can I make it temporary somehow?

I'm using it on my server, so the file stays on my server and doesn't involve the client in any way. I'm using PHP in conjunction with MySQL, so the solution may also be in PHP.

Comment: Can't you pass the path as command parameter from PHP then delete the file (from PHP again)? Note: if you really have to do it from MySQL you may do a `CALL sys_exec` for `/bin/rm`

Comment: I don't necessarily have to do it from MySQL. I'm guessing from your comment that MySQL should be kind of forced into it, so PHP would then seem to offer a more obvious solution.

Comment: yes, even if you have to expose an implementation detail I think it's not such big price to pay (and you do not hardcode paths and commands in your SQL).

Comment: php code to remove file: `if(file_exists($file)) { unlink($file); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As air4x wrote,  `if(file_exists($file)) { unlink($file); }`

Comment: Wow, didn't realize I had this almost decade old question left without an answer... Back in the day, I ended up indeed solving it like this (with PHP and `unlink`). What you do have to keep in mind, is you have the same permissions for both PHP on the folder you're using. Otherwise PHP can't delete the file.
You can perhaps solve it with pure SQL, but I remember the stuff I tried was cumbersome. It would be neatest if you could add some sort of flag to `LOAD DATA INFILE` instructing MySQL to auto-delete the file after loading, but alas.